# CSS - why does margin-top change the parent divs margin top?

Tags: html, css, margin

This is my html:

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="logoContainer">
        <p id="welcome">Welcome</p>
        <h1 class="logoText">first<img id="logoImage" src="image.jpeg" /><span id="second">second</span></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
#Header {
    font-family: consola;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#logoContainer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

#welcome {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

#logoImage {
    width: 14px;
    vertical-align: -4px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.logoText {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
}


#second {
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Now, when I change

```
#logoContainer
```

to

```
#logoContainer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 100px; // add a margin-top of 100px
}
```

the

```
#Header
```

and the

```
#logoContainer
```

get a margin-top of 100px

. How do I just give

```
#logoContainer
```

a margin-top of 100px?

Comment: Collapsing margins perhaps? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: If #Header has a height of 50px and you give #logoHeader a top margin of 100px, you won't see it.

Comment: @JoshC but even if I remove "margin-bottom: -6px;" and then apply a margin-top to #logoContainer, why does #Header still get a margin-top automatically?

Comment: @user2719875 why do you think it does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Total re-edit. So here's the deal with vertical margins.

Rule #1 - when two vertical margins in static or relative display elements meet (e.g. a bottom and top margin between two block elements in normal flow), the smaller of the two disappears.

Rule #2 - If a wrapping parent container doesn't have any padding or border, the same collapse thing  thing happens to its top margin and its first child's top margin (and similar with last child and bottom margin). The smaller one disappears and the larger one takes its place. So a P tag with a 10px margin inside a DIV with no padding, or borders will actually  push that parent DIV tag down as if the parent div had its own 10px top margin. If the parent div had had its own 15px margin but no padding or border, it would have been as if the P tag's margin had disappeared. 1px padding or border on the parent, however will stop this behavior because the two margins are no longer coming into contact with one another.

IMO, Rule #1 is great. You can basically have a bunch of content elements and always be certain that the larger whitespace need will be observed without any doubling up.

Also IMO, Rule #2 stinks. It doesn't come up quite as often as you'd think but it's really a bit of a nuisance when it does and still the reason I will sometimes only use margins on top or bottom in certain types of layout scenarios.

Comment: but even if I remove "margin-bottom: -6px;" and then apply a margin-top to #logoContainer, why does #Header still get a margin-top automatically?

Comment: I think I explained that in my edit by accident. Put 1px padding-top on #Header

Comment: wow, that is so weird.. but okay, since #logoContainer has a margin-top, shouldn't I then put "margin-top: 1px;" to #Header rather than "padding-top: 1px;"? How come adding a padding-top works but even when I add a margin-top to #Header, it still gets #logoContainer's margin-top?

Comment: I think the intent was that you could let all your text elements set the spacing between each other without doing anything with your sections (divs). It is one of the few things that after years of CSS work I still just don't understand why they thought it was a good idea.

Comment: Also, don't go crazy with the negative margins. They can get righteously confusing with collapsing and other stuff going on. IMO the best use of negative margins is when a container sets the margins for multiple items with padding but you want some elements (like horizontal rules) to expand over the padding.

Comment: From Rule #2, it's not actually the first/last child, but from any block element (since a block element fills to expand the width of the element it's in and therefore can share the same top/bottom border). Other tricks to change that behavior is to use a `padding` transparent `border` for the child instead of a margin, contain the child in another element which has a padding, set the child to be `inline-block`, or put another element with a height above it.

Comment: Fair point. It could be any number of descendants of the first child and I assume it could be a second child if the first child was out of flow (e.g. had position:absolute on it).

Answer (score 3):

What you're experiencing is called [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed)
>   into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined
>   into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

There are few ways to counteract this behavior, and in your case adding a 1px border around the parent element (e.g. `border:1px solid #0f0;`) will do.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4r43D/1/)**

Comment: A simpler example approach http://codepen.io/web-johnny/pen/KVOJQa for your statement (you can just need to un-comment the commented code so you can understand the margin collapsing according the mozilla documentation )